immigrant father running with daughter from police -- takes place in S. California?
The movie is about a single (illegal?) Latino immigrant father raising his young daughter (elementary school age) and living, I think, in Southern California.... 
the film centers on a day when something went wrong -- an accident?  -- and the father runs from the police to protect himself and his daughter...
(I can't remember if he actually committed a crime by mistake or if he is wrongfully accused of having committed a crime... I don't remember what in fact he is accused of.. maybe a hit & run?... He is either an illegal immigrant or is otherwise fearful about not being treated fairly and not being able to care for his daughter.)
In part of the film, he has his daughter pretend to be a boy so the police don't recognize them..  (There is at least once scene when they are at the beach, hoping the cops don't spot them...) 
I think I saw it on Netflix, so it could have been a TV movie... maybe it was made sometime between the mid-90s to 2010.

Approximate year of release? Was it a TV movie?

I think I saw it on Netflix, so it could have been a TV movie... maybe it was made sometime between the mid-90s to 2010..

Sounds like No Turning Back from 2001.

Mexican English teacher Pablo Fernandez seeks a better life for himself and his spoiled daughter Christina (5) after losing his wife in a hurricane. Pablo becomes a tomato picker as illegal immigrant in California. While driving his illegal employer Charlie's truck, he accidentally runs over Dinah Knightly (6), who later dies. Dumb, arrogant detective Bryant and brighter but superstitious rookie Steven Lightning investigate and set chase. Petty would be-TV reporter Soid finds out first and blackmails Pablo to take her along fleeing to Mexico or she'll report him. The Fernandez's make it to Canada. On the road improvisation gets out of hand.

The girl is disguised as a boy, and they're at the beach at some point. Here's the trailer:




yes yes yes!!! this is the movie -- thank you!!! :D

@tearjerker No problem, but don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark.
